# Separating UI components and composing them in one view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have read following two articles (https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure | https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) from which I was convinced to structure my angular project in this way:

```
-app
---components
------header
---------header.controller.js
---------header.view.html
------personaldata
---------personaldata.controller.js
---------personaldata.view.html
------history
---------history.controller.js
---------history.view.html
------app.module.js
------app.routes.js
---shared
-index.html
```

(and some more but not important for my question)

Basically I want to create independent components with own controllers, services, directives and so on to place them on multiple, different pages/views. I am currently thinking that the respective view.html files will just include ...lets say...a div tag with some pure html content. Additionally I have a "main page/view" where all these components should be placed on.

How can I achieve that with AngularJS?

My research here brought me to the angular-ui-router prject which allows multiple nested views. Is that really the way to go for. The examples did not seem promising so far as they are loading partials there and I dont see a controller for each partial/component being loaded.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.
Hope the question is clear. A small example putting two of such components in an index.html would as well be great.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers
SLi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really like this approach and using it on my projects also.

You have still options for composing htmls. You can either write directives for each components so every components can have independencies but the problem is you may want to share same data between two components so this can limit your movement and force you to write much more code then you expect.

The other way is as you mention using nested views feature of ui-router. Let me give you basic example for it...

```
$stateProvider
            .state('app', {
                url: '/',
                views: {
                    'content-left': {
                        controller: 'Ex1Ctrl as vm',
                        templateUrl: 'example1.html'
                    },
                    'content-right': {
                        controller: 'Ex2Ctrl as vm',
                        templateUrl: 'example2.html'
                    }
                    'content-top': {
                        controller: 'Ex3Ctrl as vm',
                        templateUrl: 'example3.html'
                    }
                }
            })
```

As you see we need three `ui-view` in main html with the name I give on state. So basically your html should be like this.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" ui-view="content-top"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" ui-view="content-left"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6" ui-view="content-right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much @wickY26 . Just one more question. Would you put the route config in the modules itself or in the (see above) app.routes.js (all in one file). Struggling a bit with getting everything wired at the moment. There are so many ways to do it...